# Mistake in surat al fatiha

Tags: salat, mistake, surat-al-fatihah

Salam when I was reading surah al fatiha during my prayer I think I said "Alhamdul rabil alameen" instead of "Alhamdulilahi rabil alameen". If I make that mistake in the previous prayer do I have to repeat that prayer after the next prayer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make a mistake in prayer because you didn't remember the word properly, the prayer is still valid. You need not repeat all prayers once you notice that you had an error in it.

If you immediately notice an error in your private prayer, you should repeat the section.

In common prayer, if you pray at half voice, you should continue; it is covered in community.